# Can't blur out of FormInput when clicking outside of the textbox

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I have a short form that has two FormInput fields (from react-native-elements). I've tried using several methods to remove focus (and hide keyboard) when touching anywhere on the screen outside of the text input.

```
  <View style={{flex:1}}>
  <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled">
    <FormInput
        placeholder='Phone Number'
        errorStyle={{ color: 'red' }}
        inputStyle={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 20, fontFamily: 'Roboto-Thin', borderBottomColor: 'transparent'}}
        placeholderTextColor='white'
        onChangeText = {this.onPhoneChange.bind(this)}
        containerStyle = {{ borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: '#4DB1AD', width: '90%'}}
        keyboardType='numeric'
        maxLength={10}
    />
    </ScrollView>
    </View>
```

I also tried

```
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback style={{flex: 1}} onPress={Keyboard.dismiss} accessible={false}>
  <View>
    <FormInput
        placeholder='Phone Number'
        errorStyle={{ color: 'red' }}
        inputStyle={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 20, fontFamily: 'Roboto-Thin', borderBottomColor: 'transparent'}}
        placeholderTextColor='white'
        onChangeText = {this.onPhoneChange.bind(this)}
        containerStyle = {{ borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: '#4DB1AD', width: '90%'}}
        keyboardType='numeric'
        maxLength={10}
        onSubmitEditing={Keyboard.dismiss}
        onBlur={Keyboard.dismiss}
        blurOnSubmit={true}
    />
    </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

and this method

```
  <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1} onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}>
    <FormInput
        placeholder='Phone Number'
        errorStyle={{ color: 'red' }}
        inputStyle={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 20, fontFamily: 'Roboto-Thin', borderBottomColor: 'transparent'}}
        placeholderTextColor='white'
        onChangeText = {this.onPhoneChange.bind(this)}
        containerStyle = {{ borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: '#4DB1AD', width: '90%'}}
        keyboardType='numeric'
        maxLength={10}
    />
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Unfortunately, none of these solutions worked for me.